# Continuar a pesquisa no MySQL após determinado ID

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Boa noite, 
Gostaria de saber como posso continuar uma pesquisa no MySQL, através do PHP (**$mysqli->query()**), exemplo efetuei uma pesquisa e achei um usuário ID 1584, e quero buscar outro, porém partindo do ID 1584.

Tentei com LIMIT, porém não consegui o resultado esperando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente adicionar na query: where ID > 1584